# How to cache an image being served through PHP?

Tags: php, caching, header

I'm setting the background-image of my website to a url on the server, which is a php script and which serves an image as its output. Here is the code for it:

```
   //$mime is usually image/jpeg, etc
   header("Content-type: $mime");
   $image = readfile($image);
   imagejpeg($image);
```

The issue is, each time I load my page, the image seems to be loaded again rather than being cached. Is there anything I can do about that, e.g to send a header to cache the image?

Comment: Provider the correct cache headers/control. Also, the file needs to be read "smartly" to check for changes without a full read .. if that is desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always get best results using the ETag (a `md5` hash) and Last-Modified (a past date, usually when the file was created).

for your code it will be like this:

```
$etag = md5_file($image);
$lastModified = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($image)) . ' GMT';


header("Content-type: $mime");
header("ETag: \"{$etag}\"");
header("Last-Modified: $lastModified");
header('Expires: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", ((60*60*24*45)+strtotime($lastModified)))); // add 45 days expire

$image = readfile($image);
imagejpeg($image);
```

Comment: Seems to be working in firefox, but in chrome, it still seems to load the image each time

Comment: works for me in Chrome all the time, are you hitting refresh? You should know that Chrome refreshes everything when you hit refresh, just reload that page with links ..

Comment: Ahhh, I see! Yes, I was hitting refresh

Comment: Even when i just copy paste the url and hit enter, it still seems to reload it in chrome..

Comment: Does PHP automatically handle If-Not-Modified? Alternatively, consider an Expiry header to avoid having to respond as such to client requests.

Comment: ahh, yes .. that is an option too .. I've added the `Expires` header , for 45 days .. but can be changed ..

Answer (score 1):

Use the last-modified header field and set it to a date in the past all the time.

This way the browser will receive a "not modified" reply from your server and will use the cached version of the image.

Comment: The browser will only receive a Not Modified if you tell it to send such. Which requires looking at If-Modified-Since and similar. (Or another layer could inspect the headers, I am not sure what PHP or it's hosting mechanism works.)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding a header to tell the date the image file was last modified:

```
 header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", filemtime($image)) . " GMT");
 header("Content-type: $mime");
 $image = readfile($image);
 imagejpeg($image);
```

This way the browser will be able to cache the image.

Comment: This is a start. But it will not prevent a browser from re-requesting the resource (and thus re-getting the image) .. still with the Last-Modified header. Last-Modified was designed for use with the If-Modified-Since header (etc) from the client. (Or another layer could inspect the headers, I am not sure what PHP or it's hosting mechanism works.)