# caching php served images

Tags: php, mysql, session, caching

I'm trying to serve images through php like this:

**img.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$file=$images_path.$_GET['id'].".jpg";
$lastModified = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($file)) . ' GMT';
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
header("ETag: ".md5_file($file));
header("Last-Modified: $lastModified");
header('Expires: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", ((60*60*24*1)+strtotime($lastModified))));//1 day expire

$db=new PDO("mysql:host=".$host.";dbname=".$db_name,$db_user,$db_psw);

$e=explode("/",$_GET['id']);
$post=$e[0];
$e=explode("_",$e[1]);
$user=$e[0];

$q="SELECT p.id FROM post p INNER JOIN files f ON p.id=f.post WHERE p.id=".$post." AND ";
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) $q.="p.privacy=1";
else
{
    $q.="(";
    $q.="p.user=".$_SESSION['id'];
    $q.=" OR p.privacy=1";
    $q.=" OR (p.privacy=2 AND p.user IN (".$_SESSION['id'];
    if(count($_SESSION['friends'])>0) $q.=",".implode(",",array_keys($_SESSION['friends']));
    $q.="))";
    $q.=" OR ".$_SESSION['id']." IN(SELECT tag FROM tags WHERE post=p.id)";
    $q.=")";
}
$q.=" AND f.user=".$user." AND (f.date IS NOT NULL"; if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) $q.=" OR f.user=".$_SESSION['id']; $q.=")";
$q.=" LIMIT 1";
$sql=$db->prepare($q); $sql->execute(); $post=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if(!isset($post['id'])) {header("location:".$localhost); exit;}

if(file_exists($file))
{
    header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
    readfile($file);
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<img src="img.php?id=1/1_1"><br>
<img src="img.php?id=1/1_2"><br>
<img src="img.php?id=1/1_3"><br>
```

but it's very slow, and doesn't caches images, how should I do ?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

Ok about `readfile()`, I fixed it

I updated with full code, which is required because images I'm serving aren't in the public root folder, and I have to check if current logged in user has rights to view the image using session in mysql query

**UPDATE 2**

I'd like to have:
if files.date IS NULL then don't cache image , or cache it and force reload when it changes
if files.date IS NOT NULL then cache image for ever 
I don't know which headers should I use and where

**UPDATE 3**

Here is a screenshot of headers of an image 
[image: screenshot]

**UPDATE 4**

I'd like to avoid the query execution if resource is cached, what about using session variables for caching url of images?

Answer (score 0):

This is an incredibly strange way to display a file. You don't need to `fopen()` the file. Simply echo path of each file and then let the client download the file directly.

Caching should then happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try `readfile()` instead as it reads and sends the file in one easy move.

```
session_start();
/*connecting db*/
/*query for checking images privacy through session user*/
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
readfile($_GET['id']);
```

> But if most of the time is taken reading the database and checking security, this probably wont help that much. In that case maybe you should show us that code as well, there may be some way to speed that up.

Comment: I updated with full code, is there something to improve?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a PHP script to return a file with a GET parameter.  You can generate the path in an `<img>` element and let it be served statically:

```
<img src="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

If for some reason you still need to return the image from PHP, the best way to stream it back quickly is with `readfile`:

```
header('Content-Type:image/jpeg');
readfile($_GET['id']);
```

Although you should validate the GET parameter to be a good image path first for security.  Otherwise you risk returning other files on your server to the client.

<strike>You do not need to start a session to return a file if you are not checking anything in the session.</strike>

---

Now that we see more code and that you require database calls, I would next suggest setting headers to instruct the browser to cache images for a given time.  The appropriate time frame is based on how often the data being queried is updated.  Set [cache-control and possibly other headers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching) based on your needs.

Other than that you'll have to find ways to improve database / query performance or avoid queries entirely with server-side caching.

Comment: yes I have to check if current logged is user has rights to view the images, see updated full code

Comment: see **UPDATE 2**. can you give me a code example of how to use this headers?

Comment: @Michele There are lots of examples out there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12251989/how-to-cache-an-image-being-served-through-php?rq=1

Comment: I tried the code in the answer you linked me (see update) , but still takes about 1s for each image loading . what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong. 1s is a good time for a request that requires db queries.  After the first request the browser should cache the image for 1 day. If it's not I suggest using the browser developer tools to inspect the headers and cache rules it's applying.

Comment: It seems it doesn't want to cache: "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" see update 3

Comment: Your server is returning a Cache-Control header telling the browser to not cache.  Please read up on caching: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching

Comment: I added a header("Cache-Control: private"); above header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); but still not caching

Comment: I'd like to avoid the query execution if resource is cached